# Europass logo cannot be found compiling simple CV

Tags: errors, miktex, europecv

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXstudio 2.4 on Windows with europecv package but there's something wrong trying to load the `europasslogo` file.

My `.tex` document is pretty simple so far:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,narrow]{europecv}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{europecv}
\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

But it fails with error `File 'europasslogo' not found. \begin{europecv}`. I have found the required file to be located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\doc\latex\europecv` in both `.pdf` and `.eps`. I copied the PDF file to the same directory as my `.tex` file and it now works.

But this doesn't seem it should be required at all... Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: No problem here (TeX Live 2012).

Comment: No problem also here, TeX Live 2012 on Mac OS, and compiling using `pdflatex`. You tagged your questions as XeTeX, try pdflatex maybe?

Comment: @Dror Just changed my tags... I'm actually using pdflatex (I was having problems with XeTeX and accents) but the problem persists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have already found out, it is a packaging error in MiKTeX, the files in

```
doc/latex/europecv/
```

except `europecv.pdf` belong to directory

```
tex/latex/europecv/
```

I have made a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3564682&group_id=10783&atid=110783).

**Update** 2012-09-05, Christian Schenk has fixed the bug in MiKTeX:

> The bug has been fixed. The fix will be made available with the next
>   update cycle. You can watch the MiKTeX project page for further
>   information on the next update.

Comment: I realized that, eventually, but I tried to move all of them (except `europecv.pdf`) to `tex/latex/europecv/` and it still doesn't load the logo.

Comment: You have to refresh the file name database.